# Server to translate JSON to the fronend

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, rest, backend

I'm wondering if a server exists to translate the JSON (or other format) feeds from existing web services into what the frontend expects.

For example, currently my backend team sends us JSON feeds and they doesn't always meet what we need. We could file requests for them to change the feed, however, this might not be compatible with other teams and if nothing else would take time. It would be ideal for them to make all the data available and have a layer that would translate it into what is most convenient for our frontend code.

Does something like this exist?

Clearly I could roll my own or build code for each service, but I'm hoping a system like this already exists.

Comment: yahoo pipes and YQL sound like what you desribe

Comment: Those are good for public APIs, but I'm looking for something I can install on my server for in-house APIs and potentially private webservices.

Comment: i see. you may have to write your own middle layer. node.js in particular is great for these sorts of things because it can grab json, add it to ram, and serve subsets of the ram as json; very few moving parts compared to php/sql. plus, node is very fast and one box can keep your entire org updated by pinging the remote APIs on an interval instead of everybody pinging that API on-demand. use underscore or taffyDB to slice and dice the ram into the chunks your app needs.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but I was genuinely delighted to see how easily Angular binds data. We (our small company) have also been developing a framework that generates forms from JSON based on XML configurations, but the project's still pretty much an infant.

Comment: mustache generates forms from json based on html configurations, but a pure json tool would be nice...